# Is there a rust crate for generating solana keypairs?

Tags: wallet, keypair

I'm looking for a lean rust crate to programatically generate Solana key pairs. Something like [solana-keygen](https://crates.io/crates/solana-keygen) but as a library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [solana_sdk](https://docs.rs/solana-sdk/1.11.4/solana_sdk/) crate provides this

```
use solana_sdk::signature::{Keypair};

fn main() {
    let wallet = Keypair::new();
}
```

Comment: admittedly, that class lives in an unintuitive module :)